# eBay autocomplete/suggest using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement eBay autosuggest in an opera extension using jQuery autocomplete.

eBay's JSON URL is: http://anywhere.ebay.com/services/suggest/?v=jsonp&q=test

And this is what it gives:

```
["test",["tube tester","testosterone","battery tester","tester","diamond tester","testoni","one touch ultra test strips","testors"]]
```

But it doesn't parse anything. What I'm I missing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the api documentation?

Comment: I haven't found an actual api documentation for this purpose but that is the URL where you can see the json results yourself. Here is the path for the XML too: http://anywhere.ebay.com/services/suggest/?v=xml&q=test

Comment: You can't use an arbitrary URL as a JSONP source--the service you're calling must be configured to support JSONP.

Comment: @Andrew: It does. If you call the service directly (using the link above) you will get a response in JSONP format.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I believe its not an arbitrary URL when you set it's format as JSONP and you get results as a JSONP would look like. This is amazon's JSONP link: http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&mkt=1&q=canon which the autocomplete works using the same method. These are two url's displaying words the exact same way/jsonp.

Comment: @NitinSinghal: It isn't that simple (I don't think). A callback function has to execute a function supplying it the retrieved data. There is no callback function in the linked URL, so it won't work as a JSONP api

Comment: @user1082032: They are *not* the same. For the Amazon URL, try specifying a *callback* argument. You'll see the array get wrapped in a function call. http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&mkt=1&q=canon&callback=myFn

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker is right, the server has to allow jsonp requests.  The http header is different than a simple get request.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Okay I think I've understood what you're trying to say. How can I find out whether the server allows jsonp requests or xml requests etc?

Comment: btw, using this api has any limits? I mean, if its running from the user's end it shouldn't, but if any webapp is using this, it will definitely run out if the app gets popular, right?

Comment: @3zzy No where really indicates the limitation but I would assume if the mobile/web app gets REALLY popular then I would assume they should have limits. Or maybe for consecutive calls. I would suggest to store values and check for changes every 24 hours or so. That way you're limiting your app for calls to their api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a php file which handle the json call.
Here is the javascript :

```
$("input").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          "v" : "jsonp",
          "q" : request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
                 response(data[1]);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

and the ajax.php

```
<?php
    $v = $_GET['v'];
    $q = $_GET['q'];

    echo file_get_contents("http://anywhere.ebay.com/services/suggest?v=$v&q=$q");
?>
```

I assume jQuery ajax() doesn't support "jsonp" datatype, because it was the problem all along.
You still have the same response in json though.

Comment: jQuery ajax() supports jsonp datatype absolutely fine: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ I can't see why my way doesn't work

Comment: You're right, it's supposed to support jsonp. But each time I ran your code I got a "parseerror" from jQuery with dataType on jsonp. Have you checked in bugs tickets of jQuery, maybe you'll find something, because it should definitely work. Or I'm missing the point.

Comment: That's why I'm here. There is no bug on this situation. It works absolutely find with other websites

Comment: btw, using this api has any limits? I mean, if its running from the user's end it shouldn't, but if any webapp is using this, it will definitely run out if the app gets popular, right?